# The standard deviation if the number of defective rivets in a randomly selected seam?

Tags: probability

An aircraft seam requires 10 rivets. The seam will have to be reworked if any of these rivets is defective. Suppose rivets are defective independently of each other, each with the same probability. Suppose further that 20% of all seams end up having to be reworked. What is the standard deviation of the number of defective rivets in a randomly selected seam? 
The standard deviation of a  binomial distribution with n=10 and p=0.2 is equal to 1.26 but the correct answer is 0.46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The seam will have to be reworked if any of these rivets is defective.
>
> Suppose rivets are defective independently of each other, each with
> the same probability. Suppose further that 20% of all seams end up
> having to be reworked

These are the crucial information to answer the question. If **at least one** of the rivets are defective then the seam will have to be reworked. Let $p$ the probability that an arbitrarily rivet is defective. Let X be the r.v. for the defective rivets. Then we have

$$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-(1-p)^{10}=0.2$$

Solve the equation for $1-p$ and $p$ respectively.

And finally $\sigma_x=\sqrt{n\cdot p\cdot (1-p)}$